# How can I calculate coordinates in a Tikz newcommand?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I want to do a parametric drawing with Tikz, however I do not know how to pass parameters to the package or how calculations should be made. This is a MWE but it does not work at all due to errors.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newdimen{\dh}
\newdimen{\db}
\newdimen{\dt}
\newdimen{\dr}

\newcommand{\uc}[4]{
    \setlength{\dh}{#1 cm}
    \setlength{\db}{#2 cm}
    \setlength{\dt}{#3 cm}
    \setlength{\dr}{#4 cm}
    \draw [red, thick] (0cm,\db-\dr) -- (\dr,0cm);
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\uc{10,8,3,1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might be be confusing LaTeX's `\newlength` command with the `\newdimen` TeX macro. `\newdimen` allocates a dimen register (a length that is not a “rubber length” in LaTeX-speak) and the syntax would normally be without braces, although it happens to work with braces due to the implementation doing `\outer\def\newdimen{\alloc@1\dimen\dimendef\insc@unt}` and `\def\alloc@#1#2#3#4#5{...}`.

Comment: thank you @frougon, I have heard it is not a good idea to use pure tex commands in latex macros... I did not know it, so I may not use it in my functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the question is whether you can pass an array to a command and Ti*k*Z deals with its entries, the answer is affirmative.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\uc}[1]{%
    \draw [red, thick] (0,{{#1}[1]-{#1}[3]}) -- ({{#1}[3]},0);
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\uc{10,8,3,1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here, you can get the entries 1, 2, 3, 4 of the array with `{#1}[0]`, `{#1}[1]`, `{#1}[2]`, and `{#1}[3]`, i.e. the index starts at 0. For instance, `{#1}[3]` is the fourth, i.e. last, entry of the list, `1` in this case. We need extra braces such that the parser does not stumble over the square brackets. There is no need to introduce new dimensions. The same statements apply to the `pic`s below.

If the question is how to get rid of the errors: you define `\uc` to be a command taking four parameters, but only pass to it one list, i.e. one argument, but with four entries. A minimal damage repair could be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newdimen{\dh}
\newdimen{\db}
\newdimen{\dt}
\newdimen{\dr}

\newcommand{\uc}[4]{
    \setlength{\dh}{#1 cm}
    \setlength{\db}{#2 cm}
    \setlength{\dt}{#3 cm}
    \setlength{\dr}{#4 cm}
    \draw [red, thick] (0cm,\db-\dr) -- (\dr,0cm);
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\uc{10}{8}{3}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but I think the above is better. The outcome is always the same:

[image]

I personally would not use either of them, but `pic`s, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/uc/.style={code={
\draw [red, thick] (0,{{#1}[1]-{#1}[3]}) -- ({{#1}[3]},0);}}]
\path pic{uc={10,8,3,1}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/uc/.style={code={
\draw  (0,{{#1}[1]-{#1}[3]}) -- ({{#1}[3]},0);}}]
\path pic[red, thick]{uc={10,8,3,1}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really like the first part of the answer. Does it work like an array? Introduced one parameter without the need of cm unit and so minimal. Can you please add some comments on the parts of the codes?

Comment: @EnthusiasticEngineer Yes, you can get the entries 1, 2, 3, 4 of the array with `{#1}[0]`, `{#1}[1]`, `{#1}[2]`, and `{#1}[3]`, i.e. the index starts at 0. Ti*k*Z parses the expressions automatically. As I wrote, I personally would use `pic`s.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know very little about making macros and commands. I need to read some references about this. By the way, I have to accept your answer since it solved my problem indeed.

Comment: @EnthusiasticEngineer You are welcome! Please note that pgf keys and macros differ (on the surface) in their usage. If you are loading Ti*k*Z, I feel that pgf keys are advantageous because you can always enhance your command by adding new options in form of keys while the original usage still works. (Meanwhile I personally also use pgf keys for non-Ti*k*Z tasks because of this.)